# Кэширование данных с геокодера яндекса

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Есть необходимость получать данные геокодера яндекс и отдавать их на мобильного клиента. Разумеется каждый раз запрашивать геокодер не логично и долго.
В условиях сказано что нельзя хранить данные - ок.
Но сказано что их можно кэшировать (точная фраза "Данные, полученные средствами API, нельзя сохранять. Например, нельзя один раз получить данные геокодера и затем сохранить их для дальнейшего использования. Обратите внимание, что разрешается кэшировать ответ геокодера и маршрутизатора на срок до 30 дней.").
Означает ли это что я могу кэшировать только нужные мне данные на 30 дней (в моем случае координаты) или же я должен кэшировать целиком полный ответ (json) от сервера яндекс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Связался с яндексом через форму для багов.
Ответили что можно кэшировать любую часть их данных.